# Does the Logitech F710 work on the PS3?

Tags: ps3, controllers

I can't stand the DualShock controller. Seriously, my thumb muscles start hurting. So I've been considering getting the Logitech F710 or F510.

Do they work on the PS3?  Are there any limitations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can assure you that the F710 doesn't work with the PS3, because the PS3 can't recognize the USB receiver.

Answer (score 7):

I can confirm F710 works on PS3, just make sure the switch is set in the D (legacy) position. No vibration feedback though :).

Answer (score 5):

I can't speak to the F510 or F710 specifically, but the PS3 *does* support HID devices (computer USB game controllers).  I was just able to successfully play a few minutes of *Ratchet and Clank Future: Quest for Booty* on my [RumblePad 2](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/441/264) (an older gamepad from the same series).

There are two caveats.  First, rumble was completely non-functional — either the PS3 doesn't support HID force feedback or the how rumble works has changed since my device was made.  Anecdotal evidence suggests that the DualShock 3 is itself a HID device, however, which is promising.

Second, I can't find any information on whether the "Nano-receiver" used by the F710 works with the PS3.  I'd recommend either going with the F510 (which is corded, so has no receiver) or get your gamepad from a store with a good return policy.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately if you set the F710 to direct input and plug the receiver in, you're all set .
1. make sure you have the ps3 turned on

cons do not throw away your ps3 controller because you will need it to exit a game or use sixaxis. Logitech f710 does not support sixaxis or have the Logitech button as a ps button.

Answer (score 0):

Four simple steps:

1. Change to Dinput
2. Insert Receiver into PS3 USB
3. Press any button
4. Change the left analog mode (IF YOU WANT TO, THEN ONLY)
5. PLAY!

Comment: Why is this voted down? This is a good and accurate description, especially with sertting it to DInput which is overseen by most owners of the F-Series.

Answer (score 0):

Also triggers are not pressure sensitive on PS3. 710 works on PS3. You may need to restart system while pushing buttons to make it work.